# Get List of objects with duplicates C# linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, duplicates

I have a list of objects like so :-

```
List<EmployeeModel> mList = new List<EmployeeModel>();
        mList.Add(new EmployeeModel { Place = "place1", Time = time1, EmployeeName = "abc" });
        mList.Add(new EmployeeModel { Place = "place2", Time = time2, EmployeeName = "abc" });
        mList.Add(new EmployeeModel { Place = "place3", Time = time3, EmployeeName = "abc" });
        mList.Add(new EmployeeModel { Place = "place1", Time = time4, EmployeeName = "abc" });
        mList.Add(new EmployeeModel { Place = "place2", Time = time5, EmployeeName = "pqr" });
        mList.Add(new EmployeeModel { Place = "place3", Time = time6, EmployeeName = "xyz" });
        mList.Add(new EmployeeModel { Place = "place1", Time = time7, EmployeeName = "pqr" });
        mList.Add(new EmployeeModel { Place = "place2", Time = time8, EmployeeName = "xyz" });
        mList.Add(new EmployeeModel { Place = "place3", Time = time9, EmployeeName = "abc" });
```

I want to sort the list first to find the duplicates based on the EmployeeName. Which I do as follows:-

```
var dupes = mList.GroupBy(x => new { x.EmployeeName }).Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any());
```

This gives me a group of values grouped by EmployeeName.

I have two strings ie. `placeString` and `timeString` which I want to fill in according to the different values (`Time` and `Place`) in the group of values by EmployeeName.

Something like so:-

```
EmployeeName - abc
placeString:place1 timeString:time4
placeString:place1 timeString:time2
placeString:place1 timeString:time3
EmployeeName - pqr
placeString:place2 timeString:time5
placeString:place1 timeString:time7

EmployeeName - xyz
placeString:place3 timeString:time6
placeString:place2 timeString:time8
```

How do I solve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What has this to do with sorting?

Comment: if you were doing in mvc you could have tried adding a list which would hold a employee name and list of place and time.

Comment: you dont have to create anonymous type. `new { x.EmployeeName }` just change it to `x.EmployeeName`

Comment: Also what is the logic in `Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any())`? that makes no sense to me.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary It's an interesting way to check for more than one element w/o counting

Comment: @IvanStoev why people like to make things more complicated? Come On! just write  `x.Count() > 1` :(

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Iam just a little new to c# and linq. Will keep that in mind next time :). Thanks for correcting

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary If you have a desk in your hand, and you want to know if you have more that one card remaining, will you count all the cards in order to get the answer? Seriously, it's all about performance or redundancy, otherwise using your logic, why `Any` and `All` and not just `Count`

Comment: hmm, didnt looked at it from that side! @IvanStoev ok. hello world Sorry for confusion. use `Any` solution because `x` is IEnumerable. i didnt notice its going to count all of the elements. any way its good to know that `Count` for collections does not really count elements one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the expected result? It's easy to output your desired result. Just use a `foreach`:

```
foreach(var dup in dups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("EmployeeName - {0}", dup.Key));
    foreach(EmployeeModel x in dup)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("placeString:{0} timeString:{1}", x.Place, x.Time));});
}
```